# Linux shared library is being loaded twice

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries

I have the following setup:

- a quite complex Qt+QML based application
- a shared linux library that also has some Qt functionality

The shared library is injected onto the application using the LD_PRELOAD trick. Once loaded it starts a TCP server, through which it exposes the application internal objects. The goal is to access the application internals without specifically modifying the source code of the application.

The strange thing that I am seeing is that the shared library is being loaded twice and I cannot understand why. Since both the library and the application depend on Qt, I would understand if Linux would load multiple copies of the same Qt libraries.

But the application does not depend on the shared library and I am not overriding any functions on the application itself.

I would like to know:

1. how to prevent the shared library from being loaded twice (I was thinking about using shell environment variables but it seems an ugly hack)
2. what could possibly cause the shared library to be loaded twice

### Edit

The comments from  Employed-Russian (see below) steered me in the right direction for solving question #2. The target application is launching a child process which inherits the environment variables, LD_PRELOAD included. The child process is the reason why the library is being loaded twice.

As for question #1, I also followed his suggestion: the library initialization function simply unsets the environment variable LD_PRELOAD. As a result, child processes no longer reload the library.

Comment: How do you know that the library is "loaded" twice? Just because your "startup" code in the library might run twice doesn't imply that there must be two copies of the library in the address space of the target. There might be, but it doesn't have to be so.

Comment: Indeed my startup code is running twice, and that is why I think the library is being loaded twice. In this particular case it seems very strange, but I don't know of any other reason why the startup function would be executed twice. The library is compiled with GCC and I am using the constructor attribute.

Comment: If the library is loaded twice, then it won't be loaded at the same address. You can detect that: dump the address of the constructor to the console. It should be different on the first and second load. If they are equal then *perhaps your library is loaded, then unloaded, then loaded again - and that's perfectly valid and you should handle that gracefully.*

Comment: The library is being loaded twice. I confirmed this by dumping the addresses of both the library constructor and destructor functions. But I still don't understand why this occurs for a library that is injected with LD_PRELOAD. I thought it could because the target application is forking a new process, which would inherits the parent's environment. But strac'ing the application does not show any forking syscalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what could possibly cause the shared library to be loaded twice

The loader goes through great lengths to *not* load the same shared library twice.

It is exceedingly likely that you have your code linked into two *separate* shared libraries, and *that* is what is causing all the confusion.

Setting `LD_DEBUG=libs,files` should clearly show what libraries are loaded from which paths.

Comment: @Employed_Russian, the application links against Qt libraries and the shared library that is injected in the application **also** links against Qt libraries. Is this what you mean ? If so, I would expect only Qt libraries to be loaded and not the injected library itself.

Comment: @ngoncalves No, that's not what I meant. Please read the answer again.

Comment: @Employed_Russian, there is **no** common code between the shared library and the application **and** the build process for the two is completely independent. However debugging showed the cause: the application is launching a process which then loads the shared library. I suppose it is because the process inherits the parent environment variables

Comment: @ngoncalves Yes, `LD_PRELOAD` is inherited by subprocesses. You can unset it from within the application before creating the child.

Comment: I can't. The goal of using LD_PRELOAD is to allow me to inspect the application (for testing purposes) without actually making changes to the application source code. After I added the safeguard against loading the library multiple times, all works as expected.

Comment: @ngoncalves Yes, you can: unset `LD_PRELOAD` in the library initializer for your library.